# Trying to use NOT EXISTS to check a row exists but fail

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get if the 'product' is TV and the mark is good, then I want the color is red. However, I also want to get every row of TV mark is not 'good' regardless of the color.  So I use NOT EXISTS() to check if the TV row' mark has no 'good', but it fail. did i use the NOT EXISTS() wrong or any other way? The expected output is get all product tv with color red with mark good, but also any product TV mark is not 'good' regardles

```html
<?php
$sql = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT product FROM table WHERE product='tv' AND amount IN (%s, %s, %s) 
AND mark='good' AND color=%s 
 OR NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT product FROM talble WHERE product='tv' 
AND amount IN (%s, %s, %s) AND mark = 'good') GROUP BY product 
",$amount1,$amount2,$amount3,$color,$amount1,$amount2,$amount3));
/*
product    amount      color          mark
 tv         4        red           good
 tv         5         yellow        bad
 tv         4          black         OK
 tv         6       black         bad  
 tv         4       yellow        good
 radio      5       yellow        good
 radio      6          yellow        good
*/

?>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I tried editing your code, no idea why you have code, then db schema, then a `?>`. please reformat it.

Comment: you're mixing `and` and `or` without any `()` to enforce the execution order.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your text description, I think the SQL you want will more closely resemble

```
select
  product
from
  table
where
  amount in (%s, %s, %s) and
  product='tv' and
  ((mark='good' and color=%s) or mark!='good')
group by
  product
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing your query like below

```
SELECT product 
FROM table 
WHERE (product='tv' 
AND amount IN (%s, %s, %s) 
AND mark='good' 
AND color=%s )
OR NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM talble WHERE product='tv' 
AND amount IN (%s, %s, %s) AND mark = 'good') 
GROUP BY product
```